# Loading a module from /usr/lib/modules into Apache

Tags: python, apache, loadmodule

I follows this guide http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html. And have gotten to the point where I have to load the module, but when I run the LoadModule command I get:

```
LoadModule: command not found
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I have apache installed and the mod_wsgi.so file in /usr/lib/apache2/modules directory. Here is the command I am running

```
LoadModule mod_wsgi /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Any help would be appreciated. I honestly do not understand why this would not work. I have done some research and have found nothing useful on this. To be clear I am a developer that is changing over from PHP to Python for my api coding and am non a sys admin. Have mercy on my ignorance of Apache's inner workings. I know very little about the subject.

Comment: Are you execute `LoadModule` in your bash?

Comment: I was executing it in the terminal. How do I execute it in bash?

Comment: `LoadModule` Is not command, You said "but when I run the LoadModule command", how you run it?

Comment: I am just realizing that there might be a file I need to add this to. Would you happen to know what file loads the modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian-based systems like Ubuntu, the `a2enmod` command is provided to set up Apache modules correctly. So, from your shell, do `sudo a2enmod wsgi`.

Comment: The module is loaded into apache now, but when I r un that command I get the result ERROR: Module wsgi doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

`LoadModule` is only for Apache configure file, You can't run it as a command in bash or somewhere else.

You must edit `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` in ubuntu.

[Read this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_so.html#page-header).

Comment: My installation has apache2.conf because it is ubuntu. Is it the same?

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins Ya, I changed it.

Comment: I checked my apache2.conf and I do not see any other LoadModule statements. Any idea where they might be?

Comment: So I added the line LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so to my apache2.conf file, but when i run sudo a2enmod wsgi_module, apache thinks the module doesn't exist. I can confirm that the module is loaded as wsgi_module (shared)